# resetting android device when it goes to offline mode during automation

Tags: usb, adb, offline, reset

During automation, android device is detected as offline in adb devices.

Manual usb unplug/plug helps to retrieve from offline mode.

What is the **cli cmd to detect that particular adb usb port and to reset it in windows machine** .
so that I could add it along automaton script.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

We have solved the issue in our environment (not a single device went "offline" in the last year) but the solution might not work for you.

- we switched to linux (linux USB stack seems to be more "forgiving")
- our testing framework makes sure that no adb commands are sent to any devices in the first 10 seconds since ADB interface enumeration